# Log REST request/response via Spring Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, rest, logging

My application is a middle layer(java) with REST service end point(XML). I want to log the request and response of REST. How can i use with an interceptor.
I use Spring framework, but doesnt have MVC, since the front layer is .NET. Just used only Spring AOP. Is there any possiblity to log the request/response using Spring Interceptor or via AOP?

Comment: Do you want to log just some information about the request or the request/response body as well?

Comment: I need to log both request and response, both are in xml formats. I dont use spring mvc, but only AOP.
If in AOP, does the request/response object can be accessed somehow?

Comment: If you are not using Spring MVC, why did you mention *spring interceptor* in the question? Which interceptor are you referring to? Probably not MVC's HandlerInterceptor.

Comment: I meant, to use AOP. I am not yet used HandlerInterceptor, but dont know if i could use this without having Spring-MVC. I am thinking like this, to define pointCut and to log the request before the execution of an rest end point method. It would be good to use interceptor than java filters, i think so.

Comment: The request is coming via xml, which is unmarshalled to objectin Rest end point. I actually need to log that xml, if present. The response is actually another xml which also needs to be logged.

Comment: I think I am starting to get a picture of your needs. Still need a little bit more information about your set-up. What kind of REST framework are you using? Jersey? Maybe include some code / configuration snippets in the question... I am asking because generic request/response logging is a bit complex as you are dealing with binary input/output streams.

Comment: I am using RestEasy with Spring integration. When the request is coming via xml it is unmarshalled to object via JAXB. So before unmarshalling, can i have this xml, even it is already available in the HTTPrequest.
I did a bit like this via AOP, in which i have configurued in XML a point-cut like the following configuration snippet

Comment: <aop:config>
  <aop:aspect id="requestLogger" ref="restServiceLoggerInterceptor">
   <aop:before 
    pointcut="execution(* com.rest.*.*(..))"
    method="logRequest" />
  </aop:aspect> 
  <aop:aspect id="responseLogger" ref="restServiceLoggerInterceptor">
   <aop:after-returning
    pointcut="execution(* com.rest.*.*(..))"
    method="logResponse" />
  </aop:aspect> 
</aop:config>

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with RestEasy. Please add RestEasy as a question tag and include this keyword in the question title. Add the AOP config snippet with the description of what you have tried to the question. I will then upvote this question ;).